# VUE 3 - using setInterval to remove items from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to create a simple Snackbar using VUE 3. I have done this in Vue 2 without issue, but Vue3 seems to work slightly differently.

I have saved the array of messages in the store like so:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    snackbarText: []
  },
  mutations: {
    DELETE_SNACKBAR_MESSAGE(state) {
      state.snackbarBarText.shift()
    },
    ADD_SNACKBAR_MESSAGE(state, message) {
      state.snackbarBarText.push(message)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    MESSAGES: (state) => state.snackbarText
  }
})
```

And this is what I have so far in my Snackbar.vue component:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
import { ref, watch} from 'vue';

export default {
  set() {
    const store = useStore();
    const text = ref(store.getters["MESSAGES"]);
    
    if (text.value.length) {
      let timer = setInterval(() => {
        store.commit('DELETE_SNACKBAR_MESSAGE');
        
        if (text.value.length) {
          clearInterval(timer)
        }
      }, 3000)
    }    

    return { text }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to check for length of the `text` ref in the Snackbar and call a function that starts a timer? I'm just having difficulty implementing this in Vue3 because I'm not as familiar with the Composition API yet.

The way that it should work is, messages are added to the array and are displayed to the user. After 3 seconds, they are removed from the array. Using `watch` is clunky and I'm having difficult restarting setInterval after it is stopped.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

! Rewriting my original answer which used `setInterval`.
setInterval is not applicable to this particular type of feature. You can't transition from one element to the next in a 'clean' manner.

In Vue2 you would maybe use the `EventBus` to listen for any changes to the array of snackbar message. However in Vue3 they have removed that feature. You could continue to use a EventBus like module or use [subscribe](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe).

This is the component in its entirety:

```
<template>
  <transition name="component-fade" @after-leave="checkForMoreSnacks">
    <div class="snackbar" v-if="currentSnack">
      <div class="snackbar__container">
        <p>{{ currentSnack }}</p>
        <button @click="closeCurrentSnack">Close Me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const timerInterval = 1500;
    const store = useStore();
    let timeoutToken = null;
    let snacks = computed(() => store.getters["GET_SNACKBAR_MESSAGES"]);
    let currentSnack = ref(null);

    // The event that triggers the Snackbar to initially appear.
    // Much like an EventBus emit
    store.subscribe(mutation => {
      // listen for this specific mutation call
      if (mutation.type === "ADD_SNACKBAR_MESSAGE") {
        // if there is already a currentSnack don't proceed
        if (currentSnack.value) return;

        // if no token, set the value to this settimeout function where we do:
        // 1. Set the current value to the [0] index of the snacks array.
        // 2. Remove that item from the snacks array in the store
        currentSnack.value = snacks.value[0];
        timeoutToken = setTimeout(() => {
          closeCurrentSnack();
        }, timerInterval);
      }
    });

    function closeCurrentSnack() {
      store.commit("DELETE_SNACKBAR_MESSAGE");
      currentSnack.value = null;
      timeoutToken = null;
    }

    function checkForMoreSnacks() {
      if (!snacks.value.length) {
        timeoutToken = null;
        currentSnack.value = null;
      } else {
        currentSnack.value = snacks.value[0];
        timeoutToken = setTimeout(() => {
          closeCurrentSnack();
        }, timerInterval);
      }
    }

    return {
      currentSnack,
      checkForMoreSnacks,
      closeCurrentSnack
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.snackbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;

  &__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 30px;
  }
}

.component-fade-enter-active,
.component-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.component-fade-enter-from,
.component-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

The key to this is really the `@after-leave` hook. I realized that once the displayed snackbar has been removed, we can check for more using that hook.

That hook was also the reason not using `setInterval`.

Also created a git [repo](https://github.com/RizaHKhan/vue3snackbar/tree/master/src) for this.